# What is the max and min value for itemMargin property for Stacked bar chart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am using jFreeChart to plot stacked bar chart on X axis. But I am having this requirement to control space between the two stack bars on X axis similar to gap width of Micorsoft excel.
I had just attached a sample code to demonstrate the issue. On sliding bar chart gap width is adjusted. Following is the sample code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItemCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SubCategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class DomainTranslateDemo extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static class DemoPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

        private static int SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE = 50;
        private JSlider slider;
        private DateAxis domainAxis;
        private int lastValue = SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE;
        private GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer;

        // one month (milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days)
        private int delta = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

        public DemoPanel() {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
            final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
            final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            Dimension Dim = new Dimension(590, 350);
            chartPanel.setPreferredSize(Dim);
            add(chartPanel);

            JPanel dashboard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            dashboard.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 4, 4, 4));   

            this.slider = new JSlider(0, 100, SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE);
            this.slider.addChangeListener(this);
            dashboard.add(this.slider);
            add(dashboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
            DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

            result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Jan 04");


            result.addValue(23.3, "Product 2 (US)", "Jan 04");

            result.addValue(12.7, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Jan 04");


            result.addValue(11.9, "Product 3 (US)", "Jan 04");

            return result;
        }

        private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

            final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                    "Max Bar Width", // chart title
                    "Category", // domain axis label
                    "Value", // range axis label
                    dataset, // data
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // the plot orientation
                    true, // legend
                    true, // tooltips
                    false // urls
                    );

            renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
            KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (US)", "G1");

            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (US)", "G2");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Europe)", "G2");

            map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (US)", "G3");


            renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);
            double maxBarWidth = renderer.getMaximumBarWidth();

            //renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(1);
            //renderer.setItemMargin(0.85);

            SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Product / Month");
            domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05);
            domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 1");
            domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 2");
            domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 3");

            CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
            plot.setRenderer(renderer);
            plot.setFixedLegendItems(createLegendItems());

            return chart;

        }

        /**
         * @return The legend items.
         */
        private LegendItemCollection createLegendItems() {
            LegendItemCollection result = new LegendItemCollection();
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            int value = this.slider.getValue();
           /* long minimum = domainAxis.getMinimumDate().getTime();
            long maximum = domainAxis.getMaximumDate().getTime();
            if (value<lastValue) { // left
                minimum = minimum - delta;
                maximum = maximum - delta;
            } else { // right
                minimum = minimum + delta;
                maximum = maximum + delta;
            }
            DateRange range = new DateRange(minimum,maximum);
            domainAxis.setRange(range);*/
            System.out.println("value:"+value);
            renderer.setItemMargin(value/100);

        }

    }

    public DomainTranslateDemo(String title) {
        super(title);
        setContentPane(new DemoPanel());
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        return new DemoPanel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DomainTranslateDemo demo = new DomainTranslateDemo("Translate Demo");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Also I am unable to update the chart panel according to the slider change.

Any kind of suggestion would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt look to see how MS Excel performed its spacing but you've got an issue here with integer division:

```
renderer.setItemMargin(value / 100);
```

Make sure that at least one of the operands is a floating point value. Replace with

```
renderer.setItemMargin(value / 100.0);
```

Otherwise the spacing between the stack bars will always be `0`

Comment: oh great relief now its working. At 90% whole of this chart disappears. Is there any way I will know the max value for item margin. Also chart x axis labels are not moving along with the bar chart movement. Is there any way I can move this chart labels also.